# Web Form Submission customizations of Email Handler

Tags: webforms

The webform provides the [webform_submission:values] but when sent through emails, the layout is not very readable. All values are not separated for readablitity where I can use paragraph tags to separate it.
I am assuming something like the below would be the way to do this but I cant find the right syntax to make it work.

I would like something like that I can wrap html around to create readability.
I have tried different references:

[webform_submission:values[0]]

[webform_submission:values['first_name']] where first_name is part of values

and I tried  [webform_submission:name] -- similar to the provided

Submitted by: [webform_submission:user]

How do I access my fields to do this?

Thank you!

Please Note: I have spent two days searching and watching videos of the support developer - who is awesome but I have had no luck finding syntax other than twig template php code. Sometimes simple items are difficult to sift through.

Comment: do I need to customize a twig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webform shows this as the option available:

```
Use [webform_submission:values:ELEMENT_KEY:raw] to get plain text values.
```

So if you want to format `first_name` then you can do this:

```
<p>User first name: [webform_submission:values:first_name:raw]</p>
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I am relatively new to Drupal.

Comment: i need 15 reputation to cast a vote! :( but this solved my lack of knowledge. Kudos